# Binary multiplication 1111 x 1111?

Tags: binary

I am confuse that how carry works while multiplying two binary numbers

> 1111 x 1111 =  [011100001](https://www.calculator.net/binary-calculator.html?number1=1111&c2op=x&number2=1111&calctype=op&x=97&y=26)

but how to handle carries in calculation? Can anyone please explain?

I know how to handle partial sum method when there are three 1s to be added while working out final result of multiplication, **but I don't know, how to add four 1s in partial sum?**

> How carry works while adding four binary **1**s in partial sum: (1)<sub>2</sub> + (1)<sub>2</sub> + (1)<sub>2</sub> + (1)<sub>2</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $1_2+1_2+1_2+1_2=100_2$, you add a $1$ two columns to the left to the one you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

Keep calm and carry on, so to speak.

When the carry into a given place value is at least $10$ (meaning two, of course), only the last bit stays put.  The preceding bits in the carry must be carried further into the next place.

For this multiplication you carry $10$ from the fourth place into the fifth (counting units as the first place, twos as the second place, etc), having added $1$ to that place from a previous carry.  But only the $0$ bit stays there; the $1$ bit in the $10$ goes over to the sixth place.

As you go along you will find more carries of $10$ or more, and ultimately you have to keep up the transfers all the way into the eighth place.  This makes sense because, switching to base ten, $15×15=225$ versus $2^7-1=127$.